# Simulate No Audio Input Route in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, audio, ios, core-audio, simulator

I'm making a couple audio apps, and one snag I've run into several times is code I write for the iPhone doesn't work on the iPod Touch.

When using low-level audio, having no audio input route can crash the app when initializing an audio session.

Is anyone aware of how to simulate no available audio input in the iPhone simulator?

EDIT: the iPod Touch is crashing on:

```
XThrowIfError(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, sessionInterruptionListener, self), "Initialize Session");
```

Comment: Could you post the code that's crashing on iPod Touch?

Comment: Are you doing any other AudioToolbox or AudioSession related calls before the statement that crashes?